# Are there concurrency/collision issues with d3.js csv files?

Tags: javascript, database, csv, d3.js

I've been working with SQL Server backend databases for my web applications. The web server handles multiple users accessing the same files/data at the same time without any issue (most of the time).

With d3.js using data in csv file format, I'm wondering how d3.js handles multiple users accessing the same csv file at the same time.  Will there be concurrency issues in this scenario, where it could freeze the website, until the issue is resolved?  I'm not so familiar with NOT using a backend database for data storage.

Appreciate any enlightenment.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you're just downloading a CSV file on the front end? The only issue you would experience is if your web server is unable to keep up with the load. Since this is just a static file, you're unlikely to experience issues unless the site is very heavily loaded.

If the data is not updated frequently, you should consider setting appropriate expiration headers for the CSV files so that clients can cache them.

Comment: Where do I set the expiration headers for CSV files?  In the Web.config?  How do I enable client-caching of csv file?  BTW, the csv files are stored in the web server itself.  In my case, I'm using IIS7.5.

Thanks for the response.

Comment: @user2770113 That will be in the web server config. If the headers are set correctly, then browsers will automatically cache the file. If you're unsure how to set the appropriate headers, I'd suggest posting a separate question.

Comment: Okay.  Thanks @MichaelMior